# Comparison effects of regressors for several dependent variables

Tags: least-squares, interaction, binary-data, linear

I want to study the effect of two explanatory variables $X$ and $Z$ on four different outcomes (which are binary variables, i.e. equal 1 if satisfied and 0 if disatisfied): $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $Y_3$ and $Y_4$.

I want to build a variable $Y$ that is equal to 1 if at least one of the four original dependent variables is equal to 1, and zero otherwise (i.e. it indicates the satisfaction with at least one of the 4 dimensions). Then I want to regress this new dependent variable on $X$ and $Z$.

$Y=\alpha+\beta_1X+\beta_2Z$

To understand whether $X$ and $Y$ have a differential impact on $Y_1$ compared to the 3 other dimensions, I would like to interact $X$ and $Z$ with the dummy $Y_1$, i.e. :

$Y=\alpha+\beta_1X+\beta_2Z + \beta_3Y_1X+\beta_4Y_1Z$

But given that I have $Y$ on the LHS and the dummy $Y_1$ on the RHS, I suspect I have a terrible endogeneity issue. What could be the alternative to evaluate the differential effect of X and Z on the four different dimensions that I study? I could run 4 independent regressions using $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $Y_3$, $Y_4$; but is it the best solution?

Comment: Using Y on the LHS looks pretty odd. When Y_1 or Y_2 is 1, Y=1 trivially, so your model will not learn anything with X and Z. Maybe you can write Y_1 as a function of Y_i, i=2,3,4, X and Z and so on?

Comment: I am not to understand what you mean by "your model will not learn anything with X and Z". When $Y_1$=1, then the impact of $X$ on $Y$ is $\beta_1+\beta_3$. Wen $Y_1$=0, the impact is measured by $\beta_1$ only. My idea is that $\beta_3$ would help understanding whether the impact of $X$ is different or not for observations that have $Y_1=1$.